# How to simplify a Summation within a (nested) summation: $\sum_{a=0}^{\ T/2 -1}$ $\sum_{b=2a}^{\ T-1} b*b $

Tags: summation, sums-of-squares

How Would you Simplify a summation with-in a summation,
like so

$\sum_{a=0}^{\ T/2 -1}$  $\sum_{b=2a}^{\ T-1} b*b $

I honestly have tried numerous approaches to simply the inner part first, but I get stuck, plus I am confused on exactly what would be considered a legitimate mathematical operation when working on the inner part first.
Online tools can help simplify it, but they don't provide any explanation

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It is helpful to take a look at *[Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)*.

We obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{a=0}^{\frac{T}{2}-1}}\color{blue}{\sum_{b=2a}^{T-1}b^2}
> &=\sum_{a=0}^{\frac{T}{2}-1}\left(\sum_{b=1}^{T-1}b^2-\sum_{b=1}^{2a-1}b^2\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{a=0}^{\frac{T}{2}-1}\frac{1}{6}(T-1)T(2T-1)
> -\sum_{a=0}^{\frac{T}{2}-1}\frac{1}{6}(2a-1)2a(4a-1)\tag{2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{12}(T-1)T^2(2T-1)-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{a=0}^{\frac{T}{2}-1}\left(4a^3-3a^2+a\right)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> and the right hand sum can be calculated using Faulhaber's formulas.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we represent the inner sum as difference of two sums which both start with index value $1$.
- In (2) we use Faulhaber's formula for the sum of squares: $\sum_{q=0}^n q^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$.
- In (3) we use $\sum_{a=0}^{\frac{T}{2}-1}1=\frac{T}{2}$.

*Hint:* You might also find chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik helpful. It provides a thorough introduction in the usage of sums.